# Audio Drivers that avoid "audio cutoff" or overwrite external audio hub (22.04 LTS)

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, audio-jack

## Premis

Question structured as follows: Premis, Problem, Question, Attempts.

**My PC:**

- Gigabyte X570 I AORUS PRO WIFI Mini ITX AM4
- AMD Ryzen 5 5600x (Zen3)
- Palit Dual GeForce RTX 3060Ti 8GB
- MX500 1TB (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)
- Sabrent Rocket 4.0 500GB (Windows)
- MX500 2TB (storage)

**I have some old Turtle Beach PX22** headphones and they have an external audio card, problem is that audio card automatically sets up an audio cutoff that can't be accessed or modified (I had the same problem on Windows).

They have [this page](https://support.turtlebeach.com/s/article/115000250073-PX22-No-PC-Audio-During-Quiet-Moments-of-Games-Movies?) on the Legacy support since it is a problem all the PX22 have, the solution is (I think) wrong, since it didn't work on my Windows PC anyway, and it was ONLY for Windows (of course!).

**On Windows** I tweaked stuff around and when I changed Output to Realtek HD Audio and tweaked some settings in the GIGABYTE control panel (I don't remember what, even looking at it!).

#### Duct Tape solution (hopefully: temporary)

- Volume to MAX in Ubuntu and only use the external module dials for volume control.
- Use different devices for input/output and trying different ports, a configuration eventually worked and now I use a pair of earphones as mic and another pair as output

Problems with this solution:

- I can't manage single applications audio, everything I manage through the OS is "passed through the filter" and silenced as usual.

#### Objective

Get them to work while using the system commands to control audio levels.

- Remove the cutoff

## Problem

The audio simply cuts off every time the dB get under a certain threshold. The problem is known to the company and released [this page](https://support.turtlebeach.com/s/article/115000250073-PX22-No-PC-Audio-During-Quiet-Moments-of-Games-Movies?).

## Question

- **What am I supposed to try?**

## Attempts (all failed)

- Search for different drivers didn't help much, it seems like most drivers are already installed in the kernel
- Installing PulseAudio and trying different combinations of audio outputs
- Following ChatGPT instructions that made sense, ending up in nothing and just reverting back

***p.s.***

- audio card/module/hub used to describe the external, physical, piece of plastic/electronics provided with the headphones.